# What's the difference between Synergy and Gestalt?

Tags: word-usage, idiom-meaning

I recently discovered these 2 terms while looking for a single term to represent the phrase: `The whole is greater than the sum of the parts.` Which term better represent this idea?

I'm a business analyst and this is part of a discussion I was having. `Systems` in a basic sense work best when all the parts work together; when they are separate, it doesn't work as well or at all.

Bonus question: Are there any associations with these words that would taint my use of either one in the business world?

Comment: Do the dictionary definitions of the two words not answer your question? The definitions are different. In the business world *synergy* is a very common term and will be understood by most people; I don't think that's true of *gestalt*.

Comment: @nnnnnn, No, the dictionary definitions don't answer my question, hence my post here. As I pointed out, I only recently discovered the terms, so I'm not aware of the connotations or any cultural or historical associations, which wouldn't be in the dictionary anyway.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Your title is asking something else than the body of your post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Gestalt is not an English word.

Comment: @David Many dictionaries and doctors would beg to differ with you. I agree this question is off topic, either dictionary or opinion based.

Comment: @livresque The fact that dictionaries list loan words that are only used in academic circles reflects their comprehensive nature, rather than the natural usage of the English language.  Comparison with more accepted English words (Greek in origin I presume) is clearly off-topic here.

Answer (score 2):

My sense is that synergy *leads to* gestalt. Synergy is the collective action of the parts which, when combined, result in something greater. Gestalt *is* that something greater.
Synergy is the cause, and gestalt is the effect.

In the business context, I would try not to use either word.

Use of the word “synergy” will have a negative effect on your credibility; it’s deeply ingrained in business culture as a meaningless buzzword used by people who have no real ideas to contribute. It’s too common.

On the other hand, use of the word “gestalt” will lead to blank stares or drifting attention. It’s too rare; a large portion of your audience will not understand.

Instead, I think I’d stick to the basics: use phrases like “we’ll get more out of this project than we put in” to describe what you mean in plain language.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: “My sense is synergy leads to Gestalt”. Sense? Perhaps the reverse.

Comment: My source, if you want to call it that, is >2 decades working in the business world, combined with a personal enthusiasm for language, vocabulary, and usage. 

I answered the question, as asked — focusing on the “bonus question”, as it had not been addressed well so far. 

Well cited answers are great, but sometimes opinions based on experience are useful too. This is true throughout the SE network. 

Please feel free to not upvote my answer, but I believe it has value relevant to the asker, sources or not.

Comment: @David incense? 

Answer (score -1):

The meanings of the terms are indeed close, so it is quite understandable that consulting the dictionaries left the OP puzzled as to what the difference is.

The principal difference between them is not in the meanings that would be captured in the explicit definitions of the kind that can be found in the dictionaries, but in their being anchored in very different fields of discourse. While the word *synergy* has been around for a while, in the recent decades it became an established term (some would say a buzzword) in the field of business, and that's where most of its present-day use is. Using the term (particularly using it frequently) thus tends to identify the speaker as business-school educated (unless the context has to do with medicine or related sciences). Using *gestalt*, on the other hand, tends to identify the speaker as somebody who was educated in psychology or philosophy. There is practically never an occasion for both words to be used within the same text, so the question of how they are related to each other never arises.

In so far as there is a difference in meaning between the two, it is that *synergy* involves looking at the matter from the perspective of the parts, while *gestalt* involves looking at it from the perspective of the whole. One can thus say that there is synergy between A and B, when these two things, which one has first identified separately, work together to produce something that is more than their sum. On the other hand, if something is a gestalt, one starts by perceiving it as a whole; it is only later, and with some work, that one may be able to discern what its parts are, and come to realise that it is more than their sum. The term *gestalt* was introduced into English in the context of Gestalt psychology, so some familiarity with it will help one to get the sense of how to use the word competently.

Comment: I think that it's a bit more complex than the above.  To use these words, themselves, loosely, https://wikidiff.com/gestalt/synergy

Comment: Note the part about, "Usage notes
* (term) is frequently dismissed as business jargon."  Look, what can a business have to do with drug interactions, and/or, compatibility of elements?  At best, I would venture to resolve that synergy occurs between things, whereas gestalt occurs within things.  For sure, it's just illogical to think that these terms involve things together while apart with the emphasis on either together, or apart.